# How can I remove deprecated message for circular reference handler (Symfony 4)?

Tags: symfony, methods, deprecated, circular-reference, serialization

I am trying to remove this error message:

> User Deprecated: The
>   "Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer::setCircularReferenceHandler()"
>   method is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use the
>   "circular_reference_handler" key of the context instead.

Here is my code:

```
 $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
    $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object, string $format = null, array $context = []) {
        return $object->getName();
    });
```

I made a composer update and cache clear. But nothing helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells that you should give it in the defaultContext array you can give that as third parameter in the costructor.

```
public function __construct(ClassMetadataFactoryInterface 
$classMetadataFactory = null, NameConverterInterface $nameConverter = null, array $defaultContext = array())
```

in your case it would be:

```
$encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
$normalizer = new JsonSerializableNormalizer(null,null,array(JsonSerializableNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER=>function ($object) {
    return (string)$object;
}));
```

EDIT:
I was using a JsonSerializableNormalizer and you an ObjectNormalizer then the constructor definition is:

```
public function __construct(ClassMetadataFactoryInterface $classMetadataFactory = null, NameConverterInterface $nameConverter = null, PropertyAccessorInterface $propertyAccessor = null, PropertyTypeExtractorInterface $propertyTypeExtractor = null, ClassDiscriminatorResolverInterface $classDiscriminatorResolver = null, callable $objectClassResolver = null, array $defaultContext = array())
```

and used in your program it should be:

```
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null,null,null,null,null,null,array(ObjectNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER=>function ($object) {
    return (string)$object;
}));
```

Comment: I tested your code, but I get an error message: `Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessorInterface or null, array given, called in /Users/work/project/src/Service/PagesGenerator.php on line 58` do you know why?

Comment: @monkeylove I didn't noticed that we were using different normalizers, and there was copy error in the code I gave you see my edit

Answer (score 2):

you should use it (`circular_reference_handler`) as configuration key.
For example,

```
serializer:
    circular_reference_handler: App\Service\YourHandlerService
```

I tried it in `framework.yaml` and it works.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. I get the following error message:

Comment: You should put it under serializer as i mentioned. Please read carefully

Comment: Yes, because you are using jms serializer

Comment: I am totally confused. Sorry :)

Comment: Do you have an example how your service `App\Service\YourHandlerService` looks like? When looking at code examples this is usually only a callable function...